# How do I get url from webview in react-native?

Tags: react-native

When accessing a web page in a webview, I must obtain the url of that web page.
How can I get it?

Answer (score 0):

In your `<webview>` add this:

```
onNavigationStateChange{this._onNavigationStateChange.bind(this)}
```

You can get value like this:

```
_onNavigationStateChange(webViewState){
  console.log(webViewState.url)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. And I have to write a fetch in the _onNavigationStateChange, but I want to send a request only once, but request is called multiple times. How should I solve this?

Comment: Can you share your code otherwise I will write you an example?